# Changing name of all classes in html document with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a List that shows Products. When I click on one, I need to change the class of the `<li>` so as to show that it is clicked. I got this working... But what I can't do is clear the other `<li>` that have been previously clicked so as to show it is not selected anymore.

This is part of my code, what am I doing wrong? btw, my logic here is to first refresh all classes to notselected, and then just update the list with my product id number. this can be seen on the second line of code.

I'm new to javascript, and did my research, and this is what I got.

```
function showdetails(ProductID) {           
  document.getElementsByName("ProductList").className = "notselected";
  $("#"+ProductID).attr('class','selected');
```

Comment: thanks everyone. i'm giving the right answer to h2oooooo since he/she was the first to answer, and the code worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
function showdetails(ProductID) {    
    $("[name=ProductList].selected").removeClass('selected');
    $("#"+ProductID).addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: This is definitely better, no need to complicate things with a `notselected` class, when the absence of the `selected` class tells you the same information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to iterate across all elements returned in `document.getElementsByName("ProductList")` and change `className` to each element individually.

```
var productLists = document.getElementsByName('ProductList');
for (i = 0; i < productLists.length; i++) {
  productLists[i].className = 'notselected'
}
```

Comment: @Xander That tripped me up at first too, but this is [`.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName), not `.getElementsByTagName()`. This one queries on the `name` attribute.

Comment: I was assuming they had `<something name="ProductList"></something>` which would satisfy the query.